# Login with session in codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and have following methods in my model and controller, but model is returning true whatever the value is given in input field, i don't know where i'm wrong.

*my controller*

```
    function login(){

        $username= $this->input->post('username');
        $password= $this->input->post('password');

        $result= $this->news_model->login_verify($username, $password);

        if($result!==false){
        $this->load->view('news_editor');
        }
        else{
        $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
```

*My Model*

```
function login_verify($username, $password){        
 $query = $this
        ->db
        ->where('username', $username)
        ->where('password', $password )
        ->limit(1)
        ->get('user');

 if($query->num_rows==1){
     return true;
 }
 return false;      
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try turning this

```
 if($query->num_rows==1){
     return true;
 }
 return false;      
}
```

Into this

```
 if($query->num_rows()==1){
     return true;
 }
 return false;      
}
```

num_rows is a function

Comment: It's not working either, still shows news_editor view whatever the value is supplied as username and password

Comment: Is there any more info you can give me as to what is going on "behind the scenes", outside of your example above?

Comment: Here is my view
      <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="http://localhost:81/Projects/ci/index.php/manage_news/login">

i've a database with table 'user' with just one row username as username and password as password. Manage_news is my main controller class and index of controller loads login form. If username and password matches, must load news editor view which again is a form, else reload login form

Comment: Yup, pretty standard flow. I'll think on this a bit more, because your code looks fine if you change the num_rows() bit. You loaded your model in the constructor for the controller i'm assuming?

Comment: As a second step: `return ($query->num_rows()==1);` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try :
In controller:

```
public function index(){
        $data['warning'] = null;
        if($this->input->post('username') && $this->input->post('password')){
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $this->mod_login->valid_login($username,$password);

            if($this->session->userdata('userid') > 0){
               redirect('admin/index');
            } else {
                $data['warning'] = "Username or password is incorrect !!";
            }

        }
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }
```

And in model mod_login.php

```
public function valid_login($u,$p){
        $data = array();
        $this->db->select('id,login,password,status');
        $this->db->where('login',trim($u));
        $this->db->where('password',md5(md5($p)));
        $this->db->where('status','1');
        $q = $this->db->get('users');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            $row = $q->row_array();
            $data = array('userid'=>$row['id'],
                          'username'=>$row['login']
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }
    }
```

You need load session library in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

and add encryption key in config.php
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

as already pointed by [zarathuztra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3014123/zarathuztra)

if($query->num_rows==1){

and by [f3rr31r4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265886/f3rr31r4)

if($result!==false){

also..

$result= $this-**>news_model**->login_verify($username, $password);

why do you have a login verification on a news_model?
you should create a login model and use it for login porpuses... do not mix up everthing..

Answer (score 0):

correct...

```
if($result!=false){
```

instead of

if($result!==false){

------------------//------------------------

however i prefer

```
if($result==true){
```

Any way.. 
This should be your next step..
using session

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476944/Create-user-login-with-Codeigniter

Comment: That forum post deals with sessions and variable scope. That isn't the issue here.

Comment: Sorry i commented that part out, as even my simple login code was not working, i'm trying to use session to maintain user state but stuck here with this problem. Any help'd be appreciated.Thanks